# What happened to the fourth assassin in Rush Hour 3?

Tags: rush-hour-3

At the beginning of Rush Hour 3 there are 4 assassins that come to try to kill ambassador Han. Two were shot and killed and another was taken into custody, but nothing was ever shown to the other one. The last we see of him is him getting kicked. I would have thought he was arrested too and just not questioned but later Carter says "we got ONE assassin in custody".